# Angular mat table : click on column name to sort with it

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2, angular-material-table

Hello I spent  alot of time trying to figure this out but with no clue
im trying to let the user sort with any column he clicks on  either it s data(date ) or the other column which have a type String or number
any help i appreciate it

**this is my app.component.html code**

```
<div>
  <mat-table #matSort="matSort" matSort [dataSource]="dataSource">
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Data">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header="date" > Data </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let solicitud"> {{solicitud.dataInici  | date :'short'}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Canal">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Canal </mat-header-cell>
    <mat-cell *matCellDef="let solicitud"> {{solicitud.codiCanal}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Estat">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Estat </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let solicitud"> {{solicitud.estatSolicitud}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <ng-container matColumnDef="Risc">
      <mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Risc </mat-header-cell>
      <mat-cell *matCellDef="let solicitud"> {{solicitud.decisioFrau}} </mat-cell>
    </ng-container>
    <mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="displayedColumns"></mat-header-row>
    <mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: displayedColumns;"></mat-row>
  </mat-table>
  
  <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[10, 10, 20]"
                 showFirstLastButtons 
                 aria-label="select page">
  </mat-paginator>
</div>
```

**this is my app.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit,TemplateRef ,AfterViewInit,  ViewChild, NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { Solicitud } from './solicitud';
import {HttpClient, HttpErrorResponse} from '@angular/common/http';
import { SolicitudService } from './solicitud.service';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
import {MatDialogRef, MatDialog,MatDialogConfig} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import {MatPaginator} from '@angular/material/paginator';
import {MatTableDataSource} from '@angular/material/table';

import { Subject } from 'rxjs';
import { MatSort } from '@angular/material/sort';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  dataSource!: MatTableDataSource<Solicitud>;
  @ViewChild(MatPaginator, { static: true}) paginator!: MatPaginator;
  @ViewChild(MatSort, { static: true }) sort!: MatSort;
  
  title = 'angular-bo';

  displayedColumns=['Data','Canal','Estat','Risc']; 
  public solicituds$: Observable<Solicitud[]>;
 // public Solicitudbyid$: Observable<Solicitud[]>;


  constructor(
    private dialog :MatDialog,
    private solicitudService:SolicitudService) {
    this.solicituds$ = this.solicitudService.getSolicitud();
    //this.Solicitudbyid$ = this.solicitudService.getSolicitudById(idsoli);
  }
  ngOnInit(): void {
    
    this.solicituds$.subscribe(solicitudes => {
      this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(solicitudes);
      this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
      this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      
    })
  }






}
```

**and finally app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import {MatTableModule} from '@angular/material/table';
import {MatDialogModule, MatDialogRef} from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { MatPaginatorModule } from '@angular/material/paginator';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MatSortModule } from '@angular/material/sort';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    MatTableModule,
    FormsModule,    
    MatPaginatorModule,
    MatSortModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
    MatDialogModule,
  ],
  providers: [
    {
      provide: MatDialogModule,
      useValue: {}
    },
  ],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: When you add this to onInit, do you get anything when you change the sort?
`this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => (console.log('change:', this.sort.active, this.sort.direction)))`

Comment: no i dont get anything

Comment: You added ```date``` to the ```mat-sort-header```, but this isn't declared as a column def or anything else, so by simply removing that your issue should be fixed.